# iOS Swift Core Data How to Search FetchedObjects from an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have an `Entity` called `Asset`. `Asset` has two properties *id*: `UUID` and *data*: `NSData`. I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` called *fetchedAssetsController*.

I fetch all the `Assets` using:

```
let request = Asset.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Asset>
do {
    fetchedAssetsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedAssetsController.delegate = self
    try fetchedAssetsController.performFetch()           
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not get Assets. Error:\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

I have a tableView which is then populted with the `fetchedAssetsController.fetchedObjects`

My problem is this; I need to *also* be able to search through my `Assets` by their *id* without affecting the fetchedObjects for the tableView. Currently, to find an `Asset` by *id* I'm doing the following;

```
func findIndexPathOfAssetByID(_ assetID: UUID) -> IndexPath? {
    for asset in fetchedAssetsController.fetchedObjects {
        if asset.id == assetID {
            return fetchedAssetsController.indexPath(forObject: asset)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This seems to be an incredibly unintuitive and laborious way to do it. I thought about using a second `NSFetchedResultsController` to hunt for the `Asset` I want by *id*, but I believe this will overwrite my original fetch used by the `TableView`. As I'm still new to `CoreData` I'm sure there's some functionality I'm blissfully unaware of or that I'm approaching this in totally the wrong way..

What is the best way to go about achieveing what I'm tring to do?

Comment: iterating over fetchedObjects shouldn't make any changes, you should be able to make that code a bit shorter using `return fetchedAssetsController.fetchedObjects.filter({ $0.id == dataId }).first`

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way is

```
func findAsset(by assetID: UUID) -> Asset? {
    return (fetchedAssetsController.fetchedObjects as! [Asset]).first{ $0.id == assetID }
}
```

or

```
func findIndexOfAsset(by assetID: UUID) -> Int? {
    return (fetchedAssetsController.fetchedObjects as! [Asset]).index{ $0.id == assetID }
}
```